# Banana blossoms versus bean sprouts

Tags: vegetables, vegan

What is the exact difference between been sprouts and [banana blossoms](https://veganmiam.com/how-to/how-to-prepare-banana-blossom). They look very similar, so much to make me think that banana blossoms might be a joke...

Comment: You are asking for the difference between a flower and a sprouted seed?

Answer (score 8):

They're a thing, though mostly eaten in India and other parts of asia . Banana Blossoms are actually typically found as a great big bundle like this

[image]

You basically need to remove the purple 'cover' to get the little yellow flowers 
The little yellow things are the edible parts though you need to manually remove the stamen from each. They're slightly bitter and typically cooked.

Beansprouts are... well sprouted beans - I believe typically mung or soya, and are a whole plant, not part of a plant.

In short, they're completely different in every way other than *maybe* being tubular thin edible plant parts. Swapping in one for another *isn't* something that would work.

Answer (score 3):

Bean sprouts are germinated mung beans, basically a stem, with very small leaves at one end, and the grain and perhaps rootlets at the other.

Banana blossoms are flowers, made up of petals that (in this case) form a hollow tube (each tube is a separate flower). The images in the article you linked to look indeed like banana "flowers" (or rather, inflorescences: a group of flowers forming a visual unit).